# What is the difference between string and uint(int) in solidity?

Tags: solidity, string, uint256

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.16;

contract test7 {
  function getNum() public pure returns(uint256[4] memory,string memory) {
      string[4] memory _a = ['1','2','3','4'];

      uint256[4] memory a = [1,2,3,4]; // error

      return (a,_a);
  }
}
```

What is the difference between **string** and **uint(int)** in solidity?

As in the code above, why is **uint** not like **string**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` is a datatype that supports using literal single(‘) and double(“ ”) quotes, while `uint` is a datatype that supports using positive integers. In the code above, `uint` is not like `string` due to this error: `TypeError: Type uint8[4] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[4] memory.`

Comment: I wrote it as uint256[4], why did it suddenly become uint8[4]?